# Entity model inheritance Spring Hateoas 1.0

Tags: spring-hateoas

With Spring Hateoas 0.25, we had code like this:

```
public class StatisticsResource extends Resource<StatisticsDto>
{
    :
}

public class StatisticsResourceAssembler
        extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<StatisticsDto, StatisticsResource>
{
    :
}
```

Now I'm migrating it to 1.0, like this:

```
public class StatisticsResource extends EntityModel<StatisticsDto>
{
    :
}

public class StatisticsResourceAssembler
        extends RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport<StatisticsDto, StatisticsResource>
{
    :
}
```

This however doesn't compile:

```
extends RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport<StatisticsDto, StatisticsResource>
                                                           ^
where D is a type-variable:
    D extends RepresentationModel<D> declared in class RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Try using [SimpleRepresentationModelAssembler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/SimpleRepresentationModelAssembler.html)

Comment: Thanks. That works for this simple case (and makes it even simpler), but I have more complex cases where I need a custom model class and where ``EntityModel`` is a very useful base type.
Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Spring Hateoas, see [Generics bounds too strict in RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/1122#event-2822856450). The fix will ship in 1.1.0. Kudos to the Spring Hateaos team!

Thanks